# MariaDB & Android - Implementing Message feature, Selecting users and its messages respectively

Tags: android, mysql, sql, mariadb, messenger

I have a MESSAGE table.

Its columns are

`| seq | sender_email | receiver_email | content | date | is_read | sender_profile_icon_url|`

And in my Android app, I'd like to show user list first.

You can imagine the normal messenger applications such as Kakaotalk, Line, Whatsapp, etc.

```
If A ever sent a message to B OR if B ever sent a message to A.

1. A's view

B's information(email, photo) with the most recent message between
B and A must be shown in the list(MessageUserList Activity) of A.
If you click B, you see all the messages between B and A.

2. B's view

A's information(email, photo) with the most recent message between
A and B must be shown in the list(MessageUserList Activity) of A.
If you click B, you see all the messages between B and A.
```

So, It will look like this(chanjungskim@gmail.com's view):

Left: Showing users who ever sent or received at least a message.

Right: Showing all the messages after clicking the first user(fman1335@gmail).

[image: Showing users who ever sent or received at least a message] [image: Showing all the messages after clicking the first user(fman1335@gmail)]

The thing you should know is you can send messages to yourself. Then, all the messages will be placed on the right side in green color.

The pictures seem perfect... But it is not.

What I tried with the left picture is...

```
select  m3.*
    from
        ( SELECT  m1.*
            from  message as m1
            left outer join  message as m2  ON m1.sender_email = m2.sender_email
              and  (m1.date < m2.date
                      or  (m1.date = m2.date
                              and  m1.seq < m2.seq)
                   )
            where  m2.sender_email is null
        ) as m3
    where  m3.sender_email=?
       or  m3.receiver_email=?
    order by  date desc
    limit  30;
```

What I tried with the right picture is...

```
select  *
    from  message
    where  sender_email=?
       or  receiver_email=?
       or  sender_email=?
       or  receiver_email=?
    order by  date;
```

It brings the wrong data.

the current problems are

If A and B send messages to each other, then A, B are on the MessageUserList Activity on both sides. It needs to be one respectively(e.g A sees B, B sees A.). And if A clicks A user of the list, then it brings the wrong data.

I don't know what I need to fix. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the "last" email:

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  message
    WHERE  sender_email = ...
    ORDER BY  date DESC, seq DESC
    LIMIT  1;
```

That is a lot simpler and faster than your use of the LEFT JOIN.

The 'right' query needs to use this, I think:

```
SELECT  * FROM message
    WHERE  ( sender_email= A  AND  receiver_email = B )
       OR  ( sender_email= B  AND  receiver_email = A )
    ORDER BY date
```

Comment: Thanks, I think the second query is fine. But the first one just always shows one record. There are many users but it just shows one user who sends a mail the most recently. And also, When `A` sends a message to `B` for the first time, then `A` has to see himself in the list. The `LIMIT` is just for showing 30 different people maximum. And each line must show each person's the most message. If there are 50 people. It shows only 30 different people who sent a message recently, and each line show their recent message.

Comment: I guess you need "groupwise max".